# What herbs and spices are used in Kentucky Fried Chicken?

Tags: spices, herbs

Has anyone here with an apt awareness of flavors been able to work out some of or all of the herbs and spices that are used in Kentucky Fried Chicken?

I feel I can taste paprika but I wonder what other herbs and spices are in the meal that I should include in my own dish.

Comment: Salt and pepper. That's all.

Comment: Or if you want to try the "real" recipe it is here, personally I think it's just salt and pepper though. http://food-hacks.wonderhowto.com/how-to/colonel-sanders-kfc-recipe-revealed-0118355/